# nested cursor, code won't update table outside of cursors

Tags: sql, cursor

I am working on this nested cursor. My update statement in the major_cursor is not updating the table. I know that all the looping is working because the print statements print what expect, but nothing is updating in edu_suffix_stage_test. I am hoping some one has a suggestion!

For each id, there is row of data for a major, and the year that degree was obtained. I need to string them together.

For example REID 10013 has two records for two degrees:

Civil Engineering in '38, 
and Civil Engineering in '41.

I need to build the edusuffix so it is equal to "Civil Engineering'38, Civil Engineering in '41".
I need one edusuffix per reid in the end, in edu_suffix_stage_test.

Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @reid_outside nvarchar(20), @major nvarchar(50), @classof nvarchar(5),
 @edusuffix_inside varchar(80), @note nvarchar(50), @reid_inside nvarchar(20),
@edusuffix_outside varchar(80)


DECLARE education_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT  reid, edusuffix
FROM edu_suffix_stage_test
where reid < 1005
--ORDER BY reid

OPEN education_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM education_cursor 
INTO @reid_outside, @edusuffix_outside

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @note = 'building edusuffix for ' 
    PRINT @note
    PRINT @reid_outside

    -- Declare an inner cursor based   
    -- on reid from the outer cursor.

    DECLARE major_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT v.reid, 
    v.EduMajor, v.EduClassOF
    FROM  re_education v
   WHERE v.REID = @reid_outside  -- Variable value from the outer cursor 
--order by v.REID 
FOR UPDATE of edusuffix


    OPEN major_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM major_cursor INTO @reid_inside, @major, @classof

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SELECT @edusuffix_inside = @major +' '+ @classof +', '
        PRINT @edusuffix_inside

    update edu_suffix_stage_test
    set edusuffix = case when @edusuffix_outside = null then ''+ @edusuffix_inside 
            else @edusuffix_outside + ', '+@edusuffix_inside end
    from edu_suffix_stage_test a
where  -- a.reid = @reid_inside
current of education_cursor
Print ' updated edusuffix'

        FETCH NEXT FROM major_cursor INTO @reid_inside, @major, @classof
        END

    CLOSE major_cursor
    DEALLOCATE major_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM education_cursor 
    INTO @reid_outside, @edusuffix_outside
END 
CLOSE education_cursor
DEALLOCATE education_cursor
```

Comment: I've never used updatable cursors and so, I may be wrong, but shouldn't `FOR UPDATE of edusuffix` be part of the first (outer) cursor? Also, you are updating `edu_suffix_stage_test` in the inner loop (the `major_cursor` loop), which means you may be updating the same `edu_suffix_stage_test` row more than once (because the condition is `where current of education_cursor` and the `education_cursor` doesn't move while in the inner loop) – is that by design?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is nothing wrong with the cursors.
My update statement is faulty! 
I don't know what I was thinking,  comparing a null that way won't work. I am working on a better case statement too, and will use the isnull(). I will post it when I am done.